# How to exclude from `lsof` output the libraries?

Tags: linux, lsof

I want to print in a log with the help of `lsof` the information about opened resources but I don't want the customer to see what libraries are used.
I browsed through the lsof man page but I cannot get a hold of how I can exclude only the libraries from the output. Is there an easy method to do this?

Comment: Would piping the output through `grep -v '\/lib'` be doable in your context? That way you'd have complete control over what's written.

Comment: Why don't you want the customer to see the libraries? Are you entirely sure your customer won't be able to see them otherwise? If a customer has access to `/proc/` he surely could these libraries....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This is the requirement, i don't know exactly. My guess is that the client doesn't have access to the machine and the logs are stored on an sdcard.

Comment: My point is that if `lsof` -which uses `/proc/` internally- is runnable by the customer thru your script, he can directly access `/proc/` (as soon as he is able to run some script or upload some program on the machine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sed, awk, cut for parsing output of lsof, show only those lines, which doesn't have Lnn and ltx in their 4th field.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude content from the output of lsof using it's **-d** flag along with it's negation character **^**

For example, the following will prevent the **txt** file descriptor being displayed by lsof.

`lsof -d '^txt'`