# How to filter out certain files from the output set of lsof on macOS?

Tags: lsof

I am using [lsof](https://ss64.com/osx/lsof.html) on MacOS to receive a list of files. The execution takes around a minute to finish. I could use `grep` but that wouldn't improve the execution time of `lsof`.

Does `lsof` support a *regex/filter* option to ignore certain paths? I can only find filter options for network connections.

```
% time lsof +D /Users/jack/
[...]
... 60.128s total
```

Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it the [`-d` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548653/how-to-exclude-from-lsof-output-the-libraries)? [Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) also seems to describe this.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but it doesn't seem to be compatible with `+D` as it is ignored.

Comment: I just read `"Then there are exclusion and inclusion members in the set. lsof reports them as errors and exits with a non-zero return code."` So it seems including a directory and excluding certain files ins't possible

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I use `zsh` and `bash`

Answer (score 0):

The following code options should offer some speedup.

Most of the time is spent expanding the directories.

If `tree` is not available you can install it with Homebrew:

`brew install tree`

Replace regex with your regular expression.

### Regex:

```
tree -d -i -f /Users/jack | grep regex | while read dirs; do lsof +d $dirs; done
```

### Pattern matching:

```
tree -d -i -f -P pattern /Users/jack | while read dirs; do lsof +d $dirs; done
```

### Caching

If the directories do not change you can cache the directories to a file:

```
tree -d -i -f /Users/jack | grep regex > dirs.txt
```

and then use the following to list the open files:

```
cat dirs.txt | while read dirs; do lsof +d $dirs; done
```

---

A recursive version by limiting depth to 1:
`tree -d -i -f -L 1 $nextdir | grep regex`...is possible and may be faster for sparse trees with a high pruning rate, but the overhead would make it infeasible to implement for large scale depths.